# How to run a panel with simultaneous equation model

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, simultaneous-equation, reverse-causality

I am doing a project with my professor and I am using R. We are trying to solve reverse causality problems with a set of equations. The equation system/model is below (Z is control variables set):
$$income=edu+gini+corruption+Z+\epsilon_1$$
$$gini=income+edu+corruption+Z+\epsilon_2$$
$$edu=income+gini+corruption+Z+\epsilon_3$$
$$corruption=income+gini+edi+Z+\epsilon_4$$
We believe that $income, gini, edu$ and $corruption$ have simultaneity/reverse causality issue and we used dynamic panel IV with two-way fixed effect to run each of them in R. However since we are not running a single equation, there would connection across different equations and it mostly seems like a simultaneous equation model in a panel setting, and we believe our by-equation-IV-method does not capture such connection and there might be bias.
I tried to use 3SLS with systemfit package in R, and before using that I demeaned the dataset (by individual and time) to capture two-way fixed effect (because I just don't want to manually add 200 dummies, the regression will not run either), but the results are quite far from the panel IV method and there are too many significant variables that make me feel suspicious. I want to know if there is a better way to incorporate panel fixed effect into simultaneous equation model? Or is there any other methods that could solve simultaneity problem within a systematic panel framework